# JavaScript; How to add arguments to events?

Tags: javascript, events, arguments, onkeyup

I have a website that uses pure JavaScript (no JQuery) and I would like to trap events on a textbox.
The textbox is in a table, and there may be multiple tables (with their own ID's) on the page.
The textbox is dynamically created by the Javascript and added to the table after the HTML table is delivered to the browser.

I am trying to trap the onkeyup event, and know the table that contains the textbox that triggered the event.

The function that gets attached to the onkeyup event gets called with an argument, the event itself, that gives info about the key that was just pressed.  That's great, I can get that, and I know the key, all good.

```
textbox.onkeyup = my.namespace.textboxAge;

my.namespace.textboxAge = function (event) { 
    console.log("I got the event:" + event.ToString()); };
```

What I need to do is attach additional information to the function call, so that I get the original event, plus the table or table ID.

I have thought about a closure to trap in the table reference when I attach my handler to the onkeyup event, something like...

```
var table = document.getElementByID("table5");
textbox.onkeyup = function (event,table) { 
    console.log("I got event:" + event.ToString() + " on table " + table.id); }
```

But this does not work, event is not set when the closure function is attached, so it remains null when onkeyup fires.

I have worked around this for now, but I am confused as to how to add information to events and would like to know if it is possible, and how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the argument from your event function. In your code, the `table` variable gets overwritten in the event function call. If you omit it from the parameter list, you have the original value:

```
var table = document.getElementByID("table5");
textbox.onkeyup = function (event) { 
    console.log("I got event:" + event.ToString() + " on table " + table.id); }
```

Comment: Yes, but I want the table variable, that's the whole point.  How do I get the event, plus the table?  Thanks for the attempt.

Comment: You *do get* the table variable, that's the whole point of a closure. What is it exactly with the code I entered that is not what you want?

Comment: Ah, maybe I mis-understood.  When you said 'the closed table variable gets over-written' I assumed that I would not receive the table variable.  I'll have to try it out.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Yeah, sorry for being ambiguous. What I meant to say was that in *your* original code `table` is overwritten - in my code, it is not.

Comment: Oh, I see, I apologise.  Will take a look at this over the weekend and get back to you, much obliged.

Comment: Accepting this because it's the simplest answer.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the information on which key is pressed, the original event will contain a pointer to the DOM element that triggered the event.  `.srcElement`, or whatever it is in various browsers.  This will be a reference to the textbox that fired the event.  Can't you just follow up the DOM tree from this element, by looping to `.parentNode`, and see which of your tables you hit?

**Edit:**

OK, so with that said, Looking at your code above, you can add extra information to the handler itself.  This is one way to do it, perhaps the most "correct":

```
 textbox.onkeyup = function (extra1, extra2) {
   alert(extra1);
   alert(extra2);
   alert(event);
 }.bind(null, 'foo','bar');
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/it_turns_out/u0cnzpwd/2/

Comment: Good point. I have solved this by working around the issue and over-writing the event with the table reference.  I am not really looking for a work around though, I am looking for a way to send any arbitrary additional data along with the event for the future, but this may not be possible.  Thanks for the reply, it is perfectly valid and is a good candidate for the answer if nothing specific comes back.

Comment: Alright, edited now, to what I think you're looking for

Comment: This looks interesting, I have not used bind before.  I will set it up and try it out and get back about it.  I shall try to do this over the weekend at the latest, thanks very much, greatly appreciated.

Comment: Very interesting, going to use this approach in future.  In this approach I can define a function somewhere, and then do the closure part using the bind later.  This makes for much cleaner code, which is what I was looking for.  A fiddle for it is here... http://jsfiddle.net/hiblet/0nehxqum/

Comment: Had to give the other reply as answer though, as it pointed out the fact that all I had done was over shadow a variable.  Seems odd that the site will not allow two valid answers to share points.